# Samsung device returns wrong path for Image file

Tags: android, android-file

I use the following code snippets to save an Image the user has taken on the device:

```
private void createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    image.mkdirs();

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    cameraFilePath = "file://" + image.getAbsolutePath();
}

private void saveImageToGallery(Context context) {

    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(Uri.parse(cameraFilePath));
    context.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

}
```

This works fine for most devices, some Samsungs (Galaxy S5, S3) behave strange though; my method createImageFile creates the following path:

```
 file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/JPEG_20150701_131442_-1853613631.jpg
```

but the image is saved on the device to the following paths:

```
/storage/emulated/legacy/Pictures/JPEG_20150701_131442_-1853613631.jpg
```

and

```
/storage/sdcard0/Pictures/JPEG_20150701_114009_-1853613631.jpg
```

Am I doing something basically wrong here? Or is it just Samsung not following a standard?

Comment: have you test on emulator ?

Comment: It works on the emulator as well as all devices except for Samsung.

Comment: Storage path will changed base on internal or external memory on various device

Comment: "but the image is saved on the device to the following paths" -- how are you determining this? Are you using some on-device file manager, or are you using some tool external to the device?

Comment: @CommonsWare I just looked around with adb shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paths returned to your process via methods like `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` do not have to line up with what you see from places outside your own app. Android 4.2+ tablets and Android 5.0+ phones support multiple users. Each user gets their own separate set of directories representing internal and external storage. Your process, therefore, gets paths that will be mapped to "real" filesystem paths for whatever user happens to be using your app. The details of that mapping process is manufacturer- and device-specific.

IOW, don't worry about the discrepancy. If your app is reading and writing fine, and you are able to find the files that you are reading and writing from external tools for debugging purposes, all is well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Thing is I need to use that file path for displaying the saved image with Picasso and Picasso won't find / display the image for that file path.

Comment: @Ascorbin: Picasso can find files in `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` just fine. If you are running into problems with that, ask a separate Stack Overflow question where you explain how you are putting images in `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`, how you are trying to read in those images from `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` using Picasso, and what specific problems you are encountering.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Perhaps you can have a look at the new question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31242161/picasso-not-showing-images-from-gallery-on-certain-samsung-devices