# Picasso not showing Images from gallery on certain Samsung devices

Tags: android, picasso

On some (all?) Samsung devices (Galaxy S5, S3) [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) does not display Images from the Gallery.

This is the code:

```
File[] picFiles = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).listFiles();

File file = picFile[0];
```

I tried:

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(Uri.fromFile(file)).into(imageView);
```

as well as

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load("file://" + file.getAbsolutePath()).into(imageView);
```

to no avail. On all non-samsung devices boths snippets work fine:

The path to the files do not look different from other devices, example:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/JPEG_20150706_112313_826588781.jpg
```

What could be the problem here?

EDIT: Yes I have added `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. The file exists and the Image is visible in the gallery app.

EDIT 2: This is the stracktrace from Picasso:

```
07-13 07:22:22.817  14648-14921/xy I/dalvikvm﹕ "Picasso-/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/JPEG_20150713_071858_-1853613631.jpg" prio=5 tid=51 RUNNABLE
07-13 07:22:22.817  14648-14921/xy I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.decodeStream(BitmapHunter.java:142)
07-13 07:22:22.817  14648-14921/xy I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.hunt(BitmapHunter.java:217)
07-13 07:22:22.817  14648-14921/xy I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.run(BitmapHunter.java:159)
07-13 07:22:22.817  14648-14921/xy I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.squareup.picasso.Utils$PicassoThread.run(Utils.java:411)
07-13 07:22:23.167  14648-14918/xy﹕ "Picasso-/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/JPEG_20150713_071858_-1853613631.jpg" prio=5 tid=49 RUNNABLE
07-13 07:22:23.167  14648-14918/xy﹕ at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.transformResult(BitmapHunter.java:558)
07-13 07:22:23.167  14648-14918/xy﹕ at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.hunt(BitmapHunter.java:232)
07-13 07:22:23.167  14648-14918/xy﹕ at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.run(BitmapHunter.java:159)
07-13 07:22:23.167  14648-14918/xy﹕ at com.squareup.picasso.Utils$PicassoThread.run(Utils.java:411)
```

It doesn't really seem to reveal the reason for the image not being displayed.

Picasso version is 2.5.2, I could reproduce the error on a Samsung S3 with Android 4.4.4 and a Samsung S5 with Android 5.0.

[UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) is loading the same image just fine, so it's probably a bug in Picasso, I'll probably file a bug report at their github.

**LAST EDIT:** The problem actually was an OOM exception that eluded my attention because I filtered my LogCat for the wrong keywords. I'm quite ashamed of myself now.

```
picasso.load().fit().into()
```

works and the image is being displayed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you add **android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** to the manifest?

Comment: @UditMukherjee Yes I did.

Comment: Have you enabled debugging in Picasso? Check the logcat; you may be getting an `OutOfMemoryError`. When I load pictures using Picasso I check the height and width and resize to avoid an OOM error using `picasso.resize(1000, 1000).centerInside().into(imageView);` when the image is larger than the screen dimensions.

Comment: Are you getting a bitmap failed? Have you tried checking a stacktrace?

Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context).listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
      @Override public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
      }
    }).build();

Comment: Also, what Android version and Picasso version?

Comment: @JaredRummler If you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are most likely loading very large images which can lead to an `OutOfMemoryError`. You can resize the `Bitmap` and keep the aspect ratio.

Example of getting the width and height of a bitmap without loading it into memory:

```
File file = new File("/path/to/some/picture.jpg");
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), options);
int width = options.outWidth;
int height = options.outHeight;
```

Tell Picasso to resize the image to avoid an `OutOfMemoryError`:

```
if (width > MAX_WIDTH || height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
    Picasso.with(context).load(uri)
        .resize(MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT)
        .centerInside()
        .into(yourImageView);
}
```

Comment: Not working on android L device don't know why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34149550/image-view-not-set-in-android-l-using-picasso-after-loading-from-gallery