# Image View not set in Android L using Picasso after loading from gallery

Tags: android, picasso

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null)
    {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

        String [] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePath, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
        picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        if(picturePath != null)
        {
            File f = new File(picturePath);
            final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.displayAddedPostPhoto);
            Picasso.with(this).load(f).resize(600,600).centerInside().into(imageView);
        }
    }
}
```

This is not loading image in the imageview on Android L devices while on the rest this works fine.

I tried it on a motorola android L 5.1.1 device with 2560 x 1440 image is not getting loaded

If I use Uri.fromFile I get the following message in logcat

```
Logcat shows :

 Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 18386956 byte allocation with 10384296 free bytes and 9MB until OOM"
```

Comment: Have it work on device < 5.0 ?

Comment: Yes It did work well on devices less than 5.0

Comment: @PhanSinh Did you encounter similar issue ??

Comment: try config center crop and resize image less than 600px (may be 200px). And feed back for me...

Comment: @PhanSinh did not work

Comment: it is still such a problem?

Comment: Wait me 5 minutes. I will make a project sample for you...

Comment: Do you try with other image?

Comment: Sorry, Now i'm busy. I will make project sample for you late, If you need.

Comment: @PhanSinh Thank You for your time and effort